# Tar failure on Windows Server

Tags: cygwin, tar, windows-server-2019

We're using Cygwin and Tar to create backups of some of our Windows shares. We recently migrated to a new VM and now Tar continues to fail with the following message:

```
tar: The following options were used after any non-optional arguments in archive create or update mode.  These options are positional and affect only arguments that follow them.  Please, rearrange them properly.
tar: --null has no effect
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

The command we're using is as follows:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -ctime -1 -type f ! -regex ".+?[.](pst|tgz|zip|avi)" -print0 | tar -czvf /cygdrive/(share name)/(filename).tgz -T - --null
```

I've verified the necessary accounts have access to the shares as well as the folders and files within them. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: First be sure you have an up to date install of cygwin. Then review `tar --help` and `man tar` or `info tar`. It is possible that you were running a very old and not updated version of cygwin and/or tar in the old VM.

Comment: @MVB : Why don't you remove `--null`? I don't think it has any effect anyway.

Comment: @DougHenderson, that was one of the first things we verified. On the old VM we had 3.0.7 and the new VM has 3.2.0. I did scour the man pages for tar (again) and I believe it may have helped me find the resolution...or at the very least have a better understanding of tar! I'll post my findings as soon as the process has completed and been verified. I'm wondering if maybe the newer version of Cygwin has stricter, or just updated, syntax requirements.

Comment: @user1934428, per the man pages for tar, `--null` instructs `tar` that the file names are separated by ASCII NUL character, which is what is generated in the file list with the `-print0`

Comment: According to my tar man-page on `--null`: _Instruct **subsequent** -T options to read null-terminated names_. There is not `-T` after the `--null`.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution had been staring me right in the face, as is sometimes the case. I had tried every combination of order for the commands/options, except for the last couple.

The fix for me was to put the `--null` as the first option after the tar, followed by the `-T -`.

The updated script below is now running without error.

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -ctime -1 -type f ! -regex ".+?[.](pst|tgz|zip|avi)" -print0 | tar -czvf /cygdrive/(share name)/(filename).tgz --null -T -
```